# Facebook Javascript Api Error looping number in table

Tags: loops, facebook-javascript-sdk

I want to insert data from facebook graph into a table with javascript, but i'm getting error in the iteration number.

this my code

```
FB.api('/243031772570397/members',{limit:50}, function(response) {
    if(response.error) {
        alert('error');
    } else {
        var i;
        for(i=0;i<response.data.length; i++) {
            var uid = response.data[i].id;
            FB.api('/'+uid+'/', function(response2) {                                   
                var gender = response2.gender;
                var res = "<tr><td>"+i+"</td><td>"+gender+"</td></tr>";
                document.getElementById('result').innerHTML+=res;
            });                 
        }
    }
});
```

and table getting error :

Nums | Gender |

50 | male

50 | female

50 | male

i want **nums** column like this  :

Nums | Gender |

1 | male

2 | female

3 | male

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the first call request the id and gender

```
FB.api('/146797922030397/members?fields=id,gender',{limit:50}, function(response) {
    if(response.error) {
        alert('error');
    } else {
        var i;
        for(i=0;i<response.data.length; i++) {
            var user = response.data[i]
            var uid = user.id;                              
            var gender = user.gender;
            var res = "<tr><td>"+i+"</td><td>"+gender+"</td></tr>";
            document.getElementById('result').innerHTML+=res;

        }
    }
});
```